# C: fgetc gives segfault

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault

The following code is giving me a segfault, and I have no idea why.  It is the only code in my main function other than return 0 at the end.  Also, it successfully prints "fr opened."

```
//create file pointer and open file
FILE *fr;
fr = fopen("IntegerArray.txt", "r");

if(fr = NULL){
        printf("fr is null\n");
}
else{
        printf("fr opened\n");
}

int ch = fgetc(fr);
ch = fgetc(fr);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're assigning NULL to the FILE* you open.

Change

```
if(fr = NULL){
```

to

```
if(fr == NULL){
```

Comment: I would also suggest getting into the habit of reversing the equivalence check to avoid this happening again, i.e. if (NULL == fr){

Comment: An uncommon but useful code pattern is to instead perform checks like this by placing the constant first, such as `if (NULL == fr)...`. This makes it impossible to leave off ---- @Joe got this in as I was typing :)

Comment: And the reason it prints "fr open" is because you've assigned `NULL` to `fr`, and `NULL` is usually zero, and therefore false. This is one of the reasons you'll often see people write `if (!fr)`, although I'm not totally sure if that's safe.

Comment: @ams It's safe, although personally I think it's bad style since it involves an implicit conversion to bool (`!` is a boolean operator). I dislike the pretty common `!strcmp(` pattern even more.

Comment: @unwind: yeah, I've since looked it up in the C11 standard; a null pointer is always zero, but I've learned not to assume such things without checking. In general, assuming that all pointers can be converted to an integer is broken, although it works on most platforms.

Answer (score 1):

That `fr = NULL` in the condition of the `if` is an assignment.
You probably meant a comparison: `fr == NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You got this part of it:

```
if (fr = NULL)
```

Should be:

```
if (fr == NULL)
```

or better still:

```
if (NULL == fr)
```

However I just thought I'd mention in regards to your point: `Also, it successfully prints "fr opened."` it printed that again because of the accidental assignment.

```
if (fr = NULL)
```

first sets `fr` to `NULL`, so the check essentially became:

```
if(fr)
```

With `fr` being `NULL` it evaluated to `if(0)` and thus you saw the `else`s "fr opened" message.